# Is $\{x\in R\mid A \cap Rx=\emptyset\text{ and }A \cap xR=\emptyset\}$ infinite in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Assume  $R$ is a ring and $A\subseteq R$ contains $0$. Let
$$B=\{x\in R\mid A \cap Rx=\emptyset\text{ and }A \cap xR=\emptyset\}$$

Can $B$ be nonempty?

If $B$ is nonempty, is it infinite?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit rusty with rings but I want to have a go, does $0 x = 0$ for all $x \in R$?  I know it's true for a ring with identity, is it true for a ring without identity?  I think so because $ k x = (k + 0)x = kx + 0x$  This means that $0 \in Rx$ since $0 \in R$.  So since $A$ contains $0$, $0 \in A \cap Rx$ and $0 \in A \cap xR$ and so $B$ is empty.

Comment: Can it be nonempty?!

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm pretty sure $xR$ and $Rx$ always have $0$, so if $A$ does too, then their intersection can never be the empty set.  This means $B$ won't have any elements.

Comment: In $B$, do you mean $\emptyset$ (as you wrote) or $0$? Because whatever $A$ you choose, $B=\emptyset$ ($0\in xR$).

Comment: emptyset‌‌‌‌‌. not $\{0\}$.

Comment: A more interesting question would deal with the condition $A \cap Rx = \{0\}$ etc.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: yes, I encountered the set of all regular points in a ring. then I found another generalization. in above question I tried to re-generalize it. see also the redefinition of the set $B$ in my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $0\in A\cap Rx$ and $0\in A\cap xR$ for all $x\in R$. This is because $$0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x,$$ so $0=0x\in Rx$ for all $x\in R$. Similarly, $0\in xR$ for all $x\in R$. Hence, for any $x\in R$, we have $A\cap Rx\neq\emptyset$ and $A\cap xR\neq\emptyset$, so $x\notin B$. Thus $B$ is empty.

Logically speaking, if $B$ is non-empty (that is, assuming a false statement), then $B$ is infinite by [Principle of Explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). Of course, $B$ is also a baby unicorn, but that's less interesting (or at least less relevant).

Comment: How if $$B=\{x\in R\mid A \cap R^*x=\emptyset\text{ and }A \cap xR^*=\emptyset\}$$? can it be nonempty? and if it is, is it infinite?

Comment: Since $0\in A\cap Rx$, then $A\cap Rx\neq\emptyset,$ and so $B$ cannot be non-empty.